Cypress tries to import classes from SAP UI5 library and fails
In my dummy test :
import AbstractDao from "ts/data/dao/AbstractDao";

describe("sample Test", () => {
  it("test method", () => {
    AbstractDao.getInstance("busyIndicators");
  });
});

the AbstractDao class has dependency to the SAP UI5 library and I get this error :
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel' in 'C:\schedule\time-schedule-application\timeschedule\webapp\data'
    at Watching.handle [as handler] (C:\Users\MyAcc\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\12.17.4\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\node_modules\@cypress\webpack-preprocessor\dist\index.js:212:23) 

the AbstractDao.ts file contains the import on top : import Model from "sap/ui/model/Model";  and the Model contains the import of sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel , so they chain and the tests are not even loaded and the exception is thrown.
Is there a way to tell Cypress to ignore all the files from the library SAP UI5 ? My goal is to mock the return of AbstractDao.getInstance("busyIndicators") value

My goal is to mock the return of AbstractDao.getInstance("busyIndicators") value
To do that, don't import AbstractDao, make your own version for the test.
const AbstractDao = {
  getInstance: (param) => {
    return 'a-mock-value-here';
  }
}

Your dummy test isn't very informative about the usage, but the above manual mock is simple and works as long as you don't need any real features of AbstractDao.

I just need to mock the method and also make sure that no imports are triggered from AbstractDAO to be loaded at runtime

Yes this mocks the method and does not import anything.

with  cy.stub added the class and the method , the problem is that the method is not called and the original one is called I am not testing directly by creating and instance in the test and validating it , but some other class does the AbstractDao.getInstance(). Should I somehow put this class in the cypress window?
